# Can't add data to array state in a right way

Tags: reactjs, axios, state, react-native

I'm trying to get the data from this API https://apigrad.herokuapp.com/people
and put the name of each row in the array name[], then i want to access each name inside component called "User" its variable called name.

This is the code of the User component

```
class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, avatar} = this.props;
    const userDetails = (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri: avatar}}/>
          <Text>Name: {name} </Text>
        </View>
    );
    return (
      <Card>
      {userDetails}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the main code

```
export default class SettingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name: [],
      avatar:[]
    };
  }
  render() {
    var userCard=[];
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      userCard.push(
        <View key={i}>
          <User name={this.state.name[i]}/>
        ))}
        </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MenuButton navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
        {userCard}
      </View>
    );
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
// Load async data.
  let userData = await API.get('/', {
      params: {
        results: 1,
        inc: 'name,avatar'
      }
    });

        // Parse the results for ease of use.
    for(let i=0; i<userData.length; i++){
      const Data = userData.data[i];
      const names = Data.name;
      const base64Icon=Data.image;
      const base64Icons=base64Icon.slice(2,-1);
      const avatar = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+base64Icons;
      this.setState({
        name: [...this.state.name,names]
        }
      );
    } 
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  }
});
```

The expected user to have the component user with the name of each row in the API 
but this error appears 
Invariant violation: invariant violation: Text string must be rendered within a  component.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are too many brackets inside you for loop, change:

```
 for(let i=0; i<1; i++){
  userCard.push(
    <View key={i}>
      <User name={this.state.name[i]}/>
    ))}
    </View>
  )
}
```

to:

```
 for(let i=0; i<1; i++){
  userCard.push(
    <View key={i}>
      <User name={this.state.name[i]}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```